# URL Encoding on Chrome

Tags: wordpress, url, utf-8, ascii

On my Wordpress URLs with non-ASCII characters display correctly in Safari but not in Chrome on my WordPress site. I've attempted to fix the issue by manually adding UTF-8 to the HTML, but it hasn't resolved the inconsistency in URL display between the two browsers.
***Eternal Gratitude***

I tried modifying the code, adding the UTF-8 parameter, and attempting a couple of other fixes, but unfortunately, the issue persists

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.